# Modifying an unstructured pandas dataframe into a new structured dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like below and I would like to transform it in a new DataFrame

```
# column_1  column_2    column_3  column_4
# ticket    12345     
# Date      2020-02-01
# UPC Code  Description Qty       Unit Price
# 987654    product 1   1         10
# 879756    product 2   1         7
# 987895    product 3   2         5
# ticket    12346
# Date      2020-02-03
# UPC Code  Description Qty       Unit Price
# 987654    product 1   1         10
# 997651    product 4   1         3 
# ticket    12347
```

This is an example of new dataframe:

```
# ticket  date        upc_code  description qty unit_price
# 12345   2020-02-01  987654    product 1   1   10
# 12345   2020-02-01  879756    product 2   1   7
# 12345   2020-02-01  987895    product 3   2   5
# 12346   2020-02-03  987654    product 1   1   10
# 12346   2020-02-03  997651    product 4   1   3
# 12347
```

Can somebody help me please? I am trying to figure out how to do it.
Each ticket value is a purchase order and the ticket and date values should repeat according to the products on each order.
And the rows below Upc code changes by the quantity of items purchased.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered manually parsing it with the csv package?

Comment: I didn't use csv package yet. I was trying pandas functions first as I thought I were easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need to filter blank rows and by strings then re-concat after some pivoting.

if your blank spaces are not true null values, you can convert them with the following line of code.

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace('',np.nan,regex=True)



print(df)

    column_1     column_2 column_3    column_4
0     ticket        12345      NaN         NaN
1       Date   2020-02-01      NaN         NaN
2   UPC Code  Description      Qty  Unit Price
3     987654    product 1        1          10
4     879756    product 2        1           7
5     987895    product 3        2           5
6     ticket        12346      NaN         NaN
7       Date   2020-02-03      NaN         NaN
8   UPC Code  Description      Qty  Unit Price
9     987654    product 1        1          10
10    997651    product 4        1           3
11    ticket        12347      NaN         NaN
```

---

```
s = df.dropna(how='any').loc[~df["column_1"].str.contains("UPC Code")]

s1 = df[~df.index.isin(s.index) & ~df["column_1"].str.contains("UPC Code")]


df2 = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.crosstab(s1.index, s1["column_1"], s1["column_2"], aggfunc="first")
        .ffill()
        .bfill()
        .reset_index(drop=True),
        s.reset_index(drop=True),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

---

```
print(df2)

         Date ticket column_1   column_2 column_3 column_4
0  2020-02-01  12345   987654  product 1        1       10
1  2020-02-01  12345   879756  product 2        1        7
2  2020-02-01  12346   987895  product 3        2        5
3  2020-02-03  12346   987654  product 1        1       10
4  2020-02-03  12347   997651  product 4        1        3
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! It almost did perfectly, but in my dataset I noticed that in df2 the ticket value is changing every 3 rows, i.e: ticket 12345 appears 3 times, then 12346 appears 3 times and so on. That shouldn't be happening because the product list of each ticket change to 2 products or 4 or more. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I rechecked the code, but now the ticket is appearing each 2 times..and I didn't mentioned, but as the ticket is going this way...by the end of the dataframe tickets and dates became NaN and NaT

Comment: @henriqm sorry for the delay, I think you need to inspect `s1 & s2` to see whats not filtering correctly, then amend the str.contains functions to match.

Comment: Understood! Checked and found that some date rows in column_1 has different numbers in column_4. I am trying to transform those numbers into NaN. I tried .loc to locate those rows (date in column_1 and values != NaN in column_4), change the number into NaN to then go check s & s1 codes, but this is my new issue..trying to figure out how to do it.